# Redirecting submit button to the same page

Tags: ruby-on-rails

could someone show me a way of making my button redirect to the same page that the submission took place. Here is what my form looks like:

```
<%= form_for Event.new do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_field :partycode %>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a weird question, but I'm assuming you want the same view (i.e. page).

What you want to do is render the form again.

This is accomplished by overriding which view is rendered by your controller action.

```
def new # renders new.(format) by default
  @event = Event.new
end

def create
  @event = Event.new(event_params)

  if @event.save
    # ...
  else
    # ...
  end

  render 'new' # overrides default behaviour
end
```

Then assuming you have the following views:

```
# app/views/events/_form.html.erb
<%= form_for @event do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :partycode %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>

# app/views/events/new.html.erb
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Comment: The problem is I am submitting in two different places and if I change the render in my controller both places will go to that destination. How can I seperate the two?

Comment: You don't have enough context or code here to help you.

Comment: Nevermind, thank you for your help your solution solved it :)

Comment: Still unsure what you mean by "submitting in two different places".

Comment: For example, When the user logs in they are creating an event in the users page. But for a unlogged in user they can also create events on an addsongs page

Comment: So you mean you're creating `Event` model instances in two places. Submitting in two places kind of sounds like a multi step form.

Comment: That is exactly what I mean